# Right implement dataLayer or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, analytics, google-tag-manager

I need advice. Currently, i have website. There are bookmarks on main page without reload page (onclick). Normally I would not have a problem with it, but i can´t catch relevant  data about bookmars like elementID, elementClasses etc (not possible change it).. i attached screen for better idea . Website has many language versions therefore is not possible use Click Text.

I suggest use this on every bookmark:

1. `onclick="dataLayer.push({'event': 'name-of-bookmark'});"`
2. Trigger -> custom event -> fire on: event name=name-of-bookmark
3. Tag -> UA - Event... -> fire on: bookmark-trigger

Is it right way or you have better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Am a google analytics expert. When it comes to GTM, the dataLayer is the best guy to trust on events. 
Yes the syntax `onclick="dataLayer.push({'event': 'name-of-bookmark'});"`is correct and you can TRIGGER your event using that event

Answer (score 0):

I always like to avoid inline javascript when I can, I believe it is possible to get what you want without using any dataLayer pushes and it will result in a cleaner implementation. The key is custom dataLayer value macros.

### A Simple Example

Let's take the following html example that doesn't have any classes or ids.

```
<div>
    <h2>My First Title</h2>
    <a href="#"><img src="picture.png" /></a>
</div>
<div>
    <h2>My Second Title</h2>
    <a href="#"><img src="picture.png" /></a>
</div>
```

We want to track when someone clicks on the first link but there doesn't seem to be any default macro we can use to capture the link. Here's where the custom macro comes in

Create a new macro with the following settings:

```
Macro Name = "elementFirstSiblingInnerHTML"
Type = "DataLayer Variable"
Variable Name = "gtm.element.parentElement.firstElementChild.innerHTML"
```

You can then create a trigger with the following settings:

```
Trigger Name = "My First Title Click"
Choose Event = "Click"
Fire On {{elementFirstSiblingInnerHTML}} equal to "My First Title"
```

Viola, you now have a trigger for when someone clicks on the first link without any classes, ids etc. The macro works by looking at the element's parent's first child's innerHTML which is equal to "My First Title"; setting off the trigger.

This is just one example, but you pretty much have access to the whole DOM via the gtm.element DataLayer variable that gets set on a click. It's just centered around the clicked element.

### Create your own dataLayer value macro

Here's an important tip. When developing a macro it's useful to be able to test it out in the web console. However, the console doesn't support the same dot notation as the GTM portal. So in order to develop in the console instead of

```
gtm.element.parentElement.firstElementChild.innerHTML
```

you would use (assuming the click event was the 8th event in the dataLayer)

```
dataLayer[7]["gtm.element"].parentElement.firstElementChild.innerHTML
```

If you provide me a link to the page you are referring to I could probably come up with a custom macro that would work in your situation. Also, here's a great blog on the subject as well. http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/macro-magic-google-tag-manager/ (item 14 in his list)